# How to extract and filter on nested struct fields in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, struct, apache-spark-sql, extract

Here's the data schema

```py
df = spark.read.parquet(link)
df.printSchema()

# root
#    |--user_id : long
#    |--date : string
#    |--totals: struct
#    |    |--time: long
#    |    |--views: long
#    |   clicks: array
#    |    |--element: struct
#    |    |     |--clicknumber: long
#    |    |     |--eventinfo : struct
#    |    |          |--eventlabel : string 
#    |    |          |--eventaction : string
#    |          |--item: array
#    |    |          |--element: struct
#    |    |     |    |    |--itembrand: String
#    |    |     |    |    |-- itemprice: long
```

What I'm struggling to do is creating a PySpark dataframe that contains the `date` and the `eventaction` while the `date` will be between 3/05/2000 and 4/09/2009 and `brand` will be "Stihl".

I made some trials before, but without any results.

```py
df.select(['date', explode('clicks.eventinfo.eventaction'), 
            explode('clicks.item')])

df.filter(df.clicks.item.itembrand =='Stihl')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. First I exploded every array, then selected.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn('clicks', F.explode('clicks'))
df = df.withColumn('item', F.explode('clicks.item'))
df = df.filter(
    F.col('date').between('2000-03-05', '2009-04-09') &
    (F.col('item.itembrand') == 'Stihl')
).select('date', 'clicks.eventinfo.eventaction')
```